# How to create a cumulated list of a column's elements

Tags: python-polars

For a Polars dataframe like below:

```
import numpy as np
import polars as pl
aa = np.array([1,3,5,7])
bb = np.array([2,4,6,8])
cc = np.array([3,5,7,9])

df = pl.DataFrame(
    {
        'c1': aa,
        'c2': bb,
        'c3': cc
    }
)

shape: (4, 3)
┌─────┬─────┬─────┐
│ c1  ┆ c2  ┆ c3  │
│ --- ┆ --- ┆ --- │
│ i32 ┆ i32 ┆ i32 │
╞═════╪═════╪═════╡
│ 1   ┆ 2   ┆ 3   │
├╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 3   ┆ 4   ┆ 5   │
├╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 5   ┆ 6   ┆ 7   │
├╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 7   ┆ 8   ┆ 9   │
└─────┴─────┴─────┘
```

I'd like to create an extra column so that each element of this column is a list of the cumulated list of the C1 column.  Something like below:

```
┌─────────────┬
│ c4          │
│ ----------- │
│ i32         │
╞═════════════╡
│ [1]         │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌│
│ [1,3]       │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌│
│ [1,3,5]     │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌│
│ [1,3,5,7]   │
└─────────────┘
```

Appreciate if anyone could advise a proper way to write the Polars expression.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps the most elegant way to express this is with the [`cumulative_eval`](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/api/polars.Expr.cumulative_eval.html) expression:

```py
(
    df
    .with_column(
        pl.col("c1")
        .cumulative_eval(pl.element().list())
        .alias("c4")
    )
)
```

```
shape: (4, 4)
┌─────┬─────┬─────┬───────────────┐
│ c1  ┆ c2  ┆ c3  ┆ c4            │
│ --- ┆ --- ┆ --- ┆ ---           │
│ i64 ┆ i64 ┆ i64 ┆ list[i64]     │
╞═════╪═════╪═════╪═══════════════╡
│ 1   ┆ 2   ┆ 3   ┆ [1]           │
├╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 3   ┆ 4   ┆ 5   ┆ [1, 3]        │
├╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 5   ┆ 6   ┆ 7   ┆ [1, 3, 5]     │
├╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 7   ┆ 8   ┆ 9   ┆ [1, 3, ... 7] │
└─────┴─────┴─────┴───────────────┘
```

##### Some Notes

In general, I would not recommend that the `cumulative_eval` be used in this manner.  As the documentation says:

> Warning: This can be really slow as it can have O(n^2) complexity. Don’t use this for operations that visit all elements.

That said, in this case you are more likely to run out of system RAM long before this becomes a serious performance bottleneck.

For example, if we expand the size of the dataset to a mere 100,000 rows:

```py
stop = 200_000
df = pl.DataFrame(
    {
        "c1": pl.arange(1, stop, step=2, eager=True),
        "c2": pl.arange(2, stop + 1, step=2, eager=True),
        "c3": pl.arange(3, stop + 2, step=2, eager=True),
    }
)
df
```

```
shape: (100000, 3)
┌────────┬────────┬────────┐
│ c1     ┆ c2     ┆ c3     │
│ ---    ┆ ---    ┆ ---    │
│ i64    ┆ i64    ┆ i64    │
╞════════╪════════╪════════╡
│ 1      ┆ 2      ┆ 3      │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 3      ┆ 4      ┆ 5      │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 5      ┆ 6      ┆ 7      │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 7      ┆ 8      ┆ 9      │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ ...    ┆ ...    ┆ ...    │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 199993 ┆ 199994 ┆ 199995 │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 199995 ┆ 199996 ┆ 199997 │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 199997 ┆ 199998 ┆ 199999 │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 199999 ┆ 200000 ┆ 200001 │
└────────┴────────┴────────┘
```

And look at the performance in terms of time and system RAM required:

```py
import time
start = time.perf_counter()

result = (
    df
    .with_column(
        pl.col("c1")
        .cumulative_eval(pl.element().list())
        .alias("c4")
    )
)
result
print(time.perf_counter() - start)

print(result.estimated_size() / (2**30))
```

```
shape: (100000, 4)
┌────────┬────────┬────────┬────────────────────┐
│ c1     ┆ c2     ┆ c3     ┆ c4                 │
│ ---    ┆ ---    ┆ ---    ┆ ---                │
│ i64    ┆ i64    ┆ i64    ┆ list[i64]          │
╞════════╪════════╪════════╪════════════════════╡
│ 1      ┆ 2      ┆ 3      ┆ [1]                │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 3      ┆ 4      ┆ 5      ┆ [1, 3]             │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 5      ┆ 6      ┆ 7      ┆ [1, 3, 5]          │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 7      ┆ 8      ┆ 9      ┆ [1, 3, ... 7]      │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ ...    ┆ ...    ┆ ...    ┆ ...                │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 199993 ┆ 199994 ┆ 199995 ┆ [1, 3, ... 199993] │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 199995 ┆ 199996 ┆ 199997 ┆ [1, 3, ... 199995] │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 199997 ┆ 199998 ┆ 199999 ┆ [1, 3, ... 199997] │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 199999 ┆ 200000 ┆ 200001 ┆ [1, 3, ... 199999] │
└────────┴────────┴────────┴────────────────────┘
>>> print(time.perf_counter() - start)
27.60901775200182
>>> print(result.estimated_size() / (2**30))
37.25625575333834
```

The algorithm took about 28 seconds to complete ... but creates a dataset that is 37 GB in RAM.  As such, you are more likely to run out of system RAM long before the wall-clock performance becomes an issue.

Also note that the `cumuluative_eval` expression is marked as experimental and may be subject to future change.

##### Edit: columns of type `i32`

After looking at my results, I realized that I created the columns of type `i64`, rather than `i32` (as in your example).

Nonetheless, the general results hold.  For example, using 100,000 records of type `i32`, the results are:

```
shape: (100000, 4)
┌────────┬────────┬────────┬────────────────────┐
│ c1     ┆ c2     ┆ c3     ┆ c4                 │
│ ---    ┆ ---    ┆ ---    ┆ ---                │
│ i32    ┆ i32    ┆ i32    ┆ list[i32]          │
╞════════╪════════╪════════╪════════════════════╡
│ 1      ┆ 2      ┆ 3      ┆ [1]                │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 3      ┆ 4      ┆ 5      ┆ [1, 3]             │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 5      ┆ 6      ┆ 7      ┆ [1, 3, 5]          │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 7      ┆ 8      ┆ 9      ┆ [1, 3, ... 7]      │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ ...    ┆ ...    ┆ ...    ┆ ...                │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 199993 ┆ 199994 ┆ 199995 ┆ [1, 3, ... 199993] │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 199995 ┆ 199996 ┆ 199997 ┆ [1, 3, ... 199995] │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 199997 ┆ 199998 ┆ 199999 ┆ [1, 3, ... 199997] │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 199999 ┆ 200000 ┆ 200001 ┆ [1, 3, ... 199999] │
└────────┴────────┴────────┴────────────────────┘
>>> print(time.perf_counter() - start)
15.642635091004195
>>> print(result.estimated_size() / (2**30))
18.628500409424305
```

Using `i32` lowers the wall-clock run-time to 16 seconds, and creates a dataset of about 19 GB in RAM.

Still, if we double the number of records to 200,000 records:

```
 shape: (200000, 4)
┌────────┬────────┬────────┬────────────────────┐
│ c1     ┆ c2     ┆ c3     ┆ c4                 │
│ ---    ┆ ---    ┆ ---    ┆ ---                │
│ i32    ┆ i32    ┆ i32    ┆ list[i32]          │
╞════════╪════════╪════════╪════════════════════╡
│ 1      ┆ 2      ┆ 3      ┆ [1]                │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 3      ┆ 4      ┆ 5      ┆ [1, 3]             │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 5      ┆ 6      ┆ 7      ┆ [1, 3, 5]          │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 7      ┆ 8      ┆ 9      ┆ [1, 3, ... 7]      │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ ...    ┆ ...    ┆ ...    ┆ ...                │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 399993 ┆ 399994 ┆ 399995 ┆ [1, 3, ... 399993] │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 399995 ┆ 399996 ┆ 399997 ┆ [1, 3, ... 399995] │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 399997 ┆ 399998 ┆ 399999 ┆ [1, 3, ... 399997] │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 399999 ┆ 400000 ┆ 400001 ┆ [1, 3, ... 399999] │
└────────┴────────┴────────┴────────────────────┘
>>> print(time.perf_counter() - start)
45.241694554002606
>>> print(result.estimated_size() / (2**30))
74.50990379601717
```

The result takes 45 seconds of wall-time time, and creates a dataset that occupies almost 75 GB of system RAM.

##### Edit: using `with_row_count`

> I understand that df.with_row_count() shall generate a Polars dataframe with extra column of increasing row IDs.  Is it possible to use this row ID as a parameter to call pl.col('c1').head().to_list() to generate the same C4 column?

The problem is that the [`head`](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/api/polars.Expr.head.html) expression does not take an Expression as a parameter, only an integer.  That is, we cannot use a reference to another column as the `n` parameter in the `head` expression.

For example:

```py
(
    df
    .with_row_count()
    .with_column(
        pl.col("c1")
        .head(pl.col('row_nr'))
        .list()
        .alias("c4")
    )
)
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 6, in <module>
  File "/home/corey/.virtualenvs/StackOverflow3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/polars/internals/expr/expr.py", line 3219, in head
    return wrap_expr(self._pyexpr.head(n))
TypeError: argument 'n': 'Expr' object cannot be interpreted as an integer
```

It is possible to get around this limitation by using `apply`/`map`.  However, using `apply` or `map` typically leads to single-threaded, poor performance.

For example, we can use `map` and create a function that uses `head` and `to_list` to perform the action as follow:

```py
start = time.perf_counter()

def head_func(s: pl.Series) -> pl.Series:
    values = [s.head(nbr_recs + 1).to_list()
              for nbr_recs in range(0, s.len())]
    return pl.Series(values=values)

(
    df
    .with_column(
        pl.col("c1")
        .map(head_func)
        .alias("c4")
    )
)

print(time.perf_counter() - start)
```

```
shape: (100000, 4)
┌────────┬────────┬────────┬────────────────────┐
│ c1     ┆ c2     ┆ c3     ┆ c4                 │
│ ---    ┆ ---    ┆ ---    ┆ ---                │
│ i32    ┆ i32    ┆ i32    ┆ list[i64]          │
╞════════╪════════╪════════╪════════════════════╡
│ 1      ┆ 2      ┆ 3      ┆ [1]                │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 3      ┆ 4      ┆ 5      ┆ [1, 3]             │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 5      ┆ 6      ┆ 7      ┆ [1, 3, 5]          │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 7      ┆ 8      ┆ 9      ┆ [1, 3, ... 7]      │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ ...    ┆ ...    ┆ ...    ┆ ...                │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 199993 ┆ 199994 ┆ 199995 ┆ [1, 3, ... 199993] │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 199995 ┆ 199996 ┆ 199997 ┆ [1, 3, ... 199995] │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 199997 ┆ 199998 ┆ 199999 ┆ [1, 3, ... 199997] │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 199999 ┆ 200000 ┆ 200001 ┆ [1, 3, ... 199999] │
└────────┴────────┴────────┴────────────────────┘
>>> print(time.perf_counter() - start)
243.5193853039964
```

Problem is, for 100,000 records, our run-time went from about 16 seconds to 244 seconds.

Comment: Thanks @cbilot.  That's really wonderful solution!
Two more cents, I understand that df.with_row_count() shall generate a Polars dataframe with extra column of increasing row IDs.  Is it possible to use this row ID as a parameter to call pl.col('c1').head().to_list() to generate the same C4 column?

Comment: I've added a section to discuss the use of `head` and `with_row_count`.

Comment: Awesome!  Really appreciate your guidance here. :-)